# Modifying label style when a input is checked fails

Tags: html, css

I'm having a problem with modifying labels that belong to a specific input.
Modifying a later div when the appropriate input - checkbox is checked works without problems. But if I try to use the smae method for the labels it fails. Additionally if I put an additional div around a label and try to access this instead of the label (on a checked for the appropriate input) it also fails to do anything.

My Question here is mostly what am I doing wrong there?

HTML

```
<input type="radio" id="TabOne" class="sheet-TabOne" name="Tab" checked="checked" />
<input type="radio" id="TabTwo" class="sheet-TabTwo" name="Tab" />

<div class="sheet-TabHeader">
    <label for="TabOne" class="sheet-TabOne">One</label>
    <label for="TabTwo" class="sheet-TabTwo">Two</label>
</div>


<div class="sheet-TabContent sheet-TabOne">
    First content
</div>

<div class="sheet-TabContent sheet-TabTwo">
    Second content
</div>
```

CSS:

```
label.sheet-TabHeader {
    float: left;
    width: auto;
    border: 2px solid #A52A2A;
    width: 150px;
    height: 20px;
    font-size: 18px;
    background: #fff;
    color: black;    
}

input.sheet-TabOne:checked ~ label.sheet-TabOne, 
input.sheet-TabTwo:checked ~ label.sheet-TabTwo
{
    background: black;
    color: red
    text-shadow: 0px 0px 5px black,0px 0px 5px black,0px 0px 5px black;
}

div.sheet-TabContent {
    display: none;   
    clear: left;
}

input.sheet-TabOne,
input.sheet-TabTwo
{
    display: none;   
}

input.sheet-TabOne:checked ~ div.sheet-TabOne, 
input.sheet-TabTwo:checked ~ div.sheet-TabTwo
{
    display: block;   
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AFAIU, label tag is for input tag only. You can't use it with a div tag. And it links by the input id. You're trying to link them to a div without any id.

Comment: Tnx. In essence the <div> tag was the reason why the css targeting checked and the labels did not come into effect. Tnx there!